# convert first column from hex to decimal using awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, hex

I have a log file which contains logs time stamp in Hexadecimal in column one and then log text in rest of the columns.For example:

```
B60C0056: aaa1 bb1 ccc1 ddd1 eee1 fff
B60C0056: aaa2 bb2 ccc2 ddd2 eee2 fff
B60C0057: aaa3 bb3 ccc3 ddd3 eee3 fff
B60C0058: aaa4 bb4 ccc4 ddd4 eee4 fff
B60C0059: aaa5 bb5 ccc5 ddd5 eee5 fff
```

I need to convert the first column to decimal and I am using the following way to do so,but don't know how to implement this for the whole file.

```
while read line
do
echo -e "$line"|awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
done <temp
```

But how to convert $1 to the decimal value?

```
echo "ibase=16; `awk '{print $1}'`" | bc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
gawk --non-decimal-data '{ $1 = sprintf("%d:", "0x" $1) } 1' filename
```

This is a little bastardized: `"0x" $1` concatenates `0x` and the first field as string, `sprintf` then proceeds to interpret it as a number, which is parsed as hexadecimal because of the `0x` and `--non-decimal-data`. This will only work with GNU awk.

Alternatively, consider using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+/hex($&)/e' filename
```

This should work everywhere where Perl is available (which should be everywhere, really).

**EDIT:** Better Perl solution.

Comment: This works but has the problem of not right aligning the values on the first column which them misaligns the whole dump.

Answer (score 9):

`awk`'s  `strtonum` function can take care of that:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$1=strtonum("0x" $1)} 1' file
3054239830: aaa1 bb1 ccc1 ddd1 eee1 fff
3054239830: aaa2 bb2 ccc2 ddd2 eee2 fff
3054239831: aaa3 bb3 ccc3 ddd3 eee3 fff
3054239832: aaa4 bb4 ccc4 ddd4 eee4 fff
3054239833: aaa5 bb5 ccc5 ddd5 eee5 fff
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same :D Note it is gawk https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strtonum-Function.html

Comment: This is great for 1 column but how would you do 2 columns?

Comment: Same command would work for `$2` also

Comment: Thx figured it out `gawk --non-decimal-data '{$2=sprintf("%d:","0x"$2)}{$3=sprintf("%d:","0x"$3)}1' /proc/mtd`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk --non-decimal-data -F':' '{printf "%d:%s\n", "0x" $1, $2}' INPUT
3054239830: aaa1 bb1 ccc1 ddd1 eee1 fff
3054239830: aaa2 bb2 ccc2 ddd2 eee2 fff
3054239831: aaa3 bb3 ccc3 ddd3 eee3 fff
3054239832: aaa4 bb4 ccc4 ddd4 eee4 fff
3054239833: aaa5 bb5 ccc5 ddd5 eee5 fff
```